Promise.finally breaking Promise.catch depending on how I assign it
I admit I'm not a JavaScript promises expert, but this is bizarre. I'm creating an API service that's basically an Axios promise factory and importing it into Vue2 components.
The simplified example is here
function axiosService() {
    const execution = // compose axios request method

    const axiosPromise = execution(data)
        .finally(() => {
            isFetching = false;
        });

    //other inconsequential stuff
    return {
        promise: axiosPromise,
        // other stuff
    };
}

export default axiosService;

Then the calling vue component imports it and calls
            this.axiosPromise = axiosService().promise;
            this.axiosPromise.catch((e) => {
                    console.log(e);
                });

And it works fine, but i just spend a whole day debugging because the original definition of the axiosService was
function axiosService() {
    const execution = // compose axios request method

    const axiosPromise = execution(data);
        
    axiosPromise.finally(() => {
            isFetching = false;
        });

    //other inconsequential stuff
    return {
        promise: axiosPromise,
        // other stuff
    };
}

export default axiosService;

attaching the same finally to the axiosPromise const in a separate step. When done this way, either the error propogates or else axios generates a new error, but the app crashes with a runtime error
Am I missing a nuance of promises that could cause this?
thank you

For added context the execution method is just using our axios client and assembling a url, method, headers, data and returning the axios promise. Also everything works great except for errors not specifically addressed in the axios interceptor. And only when the finally is attached in a separate step

I don't see how axiosService().catch(...) can work.axiosService() returns an object containing a promise, not the promise itself. It should be axiosService().promise.catch(...)

In the first version you're setting axiosPromise to the promise returned by .finally(). In the second version you're setting it to the promise returned by execution(). They're two different promises.

@Barmar - thank you. the original code was more complex and my simplification to isolate the error had the mistake you identified. Updating it.

@Barmar - I think you clarified it for me? In the second case the calling component is successfully catching the error in execution()'s promise, but since finally is a separate promise, the error for THAT promise is unhandled and finally is passing it forward, thus an uncaught error. Am I understanding? If so thank you so much

I think you've got the idea. I think your original assumption was that this was a fluent interface, simply passing the same promise along through the chain of calls.

yes, it's perfect and I've saved this. wish it hadnt been closed as a dupe so I could accept your answer
